# Why webview.page() of Playwright Android never resolves?

Tags: android, playwright

I'm trying to set up a test in Playwright for a native Android device. I'm following their official document [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-android).

Here is the part that I have issues with:

```
    const webview = await device.webView({ pkg: 'org.my_own_package_name' });
    const page = await webview.page();
```

I can get access to the web view (have verified it by logging the web view object) but the line that says `webview.page();` never gets resolved. I have tried using the verbose mode to see if it gives me more information but here is what I get:

[image]

I'm testing on a Pixel 7 Pro API UpsideDonwCake arm64.
Why do you think the second line does not get resolved and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Beyond that, can you share a runnable [mcve]?